# use generic type in typescript as property

Tags: typescript

I want to somehow achieve something like this in typescript:

```
export type CoordinateSelector = <T>(d: Coordinate) => d[T];

export interface LinkVerticalLineProps {
  x: CoordinateSelector<'x'>;
  y: CoordinateSelector<'y'>;
}
```

I don't want to create `x` and `y` coordinate selectors like this:

```
export interface LinkVerticalLineProps {
  x: (d: {x: number}) => d.x;
  y: (d: {y: number}) => d.y;
}
```

Is this type of thing possible?

Comment: What's `Coordinate`?  Are you just asking for `type CoordinateSelector<K extends keyof Coordinate> = (d: Coordinate) => Coordinate[K]` maybe?  I'm not sure what you mean since the code you wrote at the bottom does not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is about the typings only, the answer would be:

```
export type CoordinateSelector<T extends keyof Coordinate> = (d: Coordinate) => typeof d[T];

export interface LinkVerticalLineProps {
  x: CoordinateSelector<'x'>;
  y: CoordinateSelector<'y'>;
}
```

An `interface` is a type only — it cannot be executed. You still need to supply actual code that will exist in runtime. For example:

```
const getX: CoordinateSelector<'x'> = coordinate => coordinate.x;
```

Comment: yes, this is types only.  is there a name for this pattern?  i’m struggling to find any docs

Comment: I don't think it has a name — but you can find more when you look for "keyof" and "lookup types". See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this construction?

```
export class A<T> {
    public g: new () => T;
    public o: T;

    constructor(g: { new(): T }) {
        this.g = g;
        this.o = new this.g();
    }
}
```